# Footer layout using CSS

Tags: css

I am having trouble styling my footer for and need some guidance. The name is meant to be on the left and the links on the right. The links have collapsed on me and I am wondering if there is a better way of aligning them all together more effectively. I have played around trying to use flexbox here with limited success.  Thank you for your help in advance.

```css
/* footer styles*/

footer { margin-top:1em; display: block; border-top: solid 2px #456e6e;
margin-bottom: 1em; }

top {

float: right;
text-decoration:none;
color: #456e6e;
margin-top: -2.25em;
}

top:hover{

color:black;
}

footer a { text-decoration: none; color: #456e6e; }

footer a:hover{ color:black; }

wrapper {

min-height: 100vh;
}

/*NAV CSS*/

.tablet-info {

display: none;
} for small screen sizes

for larger screen sizes

.tablet-info {

display: inline-block;
float: right;
margin-top: -2em;
margin-right:.25em;
margin-left:.25em;
}

student-name {

margin-top: 1.8em;
}

.clearfix { content: ""; display: table; clear: both; }

}
```

```html
  <div id="footer">
        <footer class="clearfix">
            <h3 id="student-name">Tracy Excell</h3>
                <h3><a href="#home" id="top">Back To Top</a></h3>
                <h3><a href="#home" class="tablet-info">Home</a></h3>
                <h3><a href="#portfolio" class="tablet-info">Portfolio</a></h3>
                <h3><a href="#contact" class="tablet-info">Contact</a></h3>

        </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS is invalid. Run it through the validator and fix those errors first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an updated footer layout and use flexbox like shown below:

```css
footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .nav{
  display: flex;
}

.nav h3{
  margin-left: 15px; 
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h3 id="student-name">Tracy Excell</h3>
  <div class="nav">
    <h3><a href="#home" id="top">Back To Top</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#home" class="tablet-info">Home</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#portfolio" class="tablet-info">Portfolio</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#contact" class="tablet-info">Contact</a></h3>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the name and link in the same tag to keep them on same line.
You can use"&nbsp;" to seperate name and link.

Every time you create an new heading, it will always starts from new line.

Comment: Never use entities to take the place of CSS styling.